# Adding a timeout to google.earth.createInstance()

Tags: javascript, error-handling, google-earth-plugin

I am trying to add some functionality to the following code.

I want to make the `geeInit()` method call `google.earth.createInstance()`, wait for 5 seconds , then if we did not get in to the mygeeEarthPluginInitCb i.e. Google earth plug-in instance is not created then recall `google.earth.createInstance()`

In effect I don't want to wait for getting into `geeEarthPluginFailureCb` method.

```
function geeInit() {
    google.earth.createInstance(geeDivIds.map, mygeeEarthPluginInitCb,
            geeEarthPluginFailureCb, earthArgs);

}

function mygeeEarthPluginInitCb(object) {
}

function geeEarthPluginFailureCb(message) {
}
```

I was wondering if `google.earth.createInstance` supports and timeout variable like regular ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like `setInterval` to run the `createInstance` method every x seconds.

When `success` is called the `clearInterval` method stops the setInterval method.

e.g.

```
var loadInterval;

function init() {
  loadInterval = setInterval(function () {
    google.earth.createInstance("id", success, function(){}, null);
  }, 5000);
}

function success(object) { 
   clearInterval(loadInterval);
}
```

That said I am not sure why you would want to do this. Are you having initialization issues with the GEPlugin?

To answer your question there is no `timeout` option/setting for the `createInstance` method.

Comment: Thanks Fraser, I am looking for something exactly like that. Regarding the initialization issues, yes I am having initialization issue and they are documented on "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562877/sometimes-initialization-of-google-earth-plugin-fails-in-ie10" I have added the google's response also.